# Eclipse Luna 1.7 to 1.8 errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working in Eclipse Luna and tried to write a static method in an interface but it gave me an error. I moused over it and I forgot what it said but it was something  like `... 1.8 JRE`. So I clicked it and now there's an error on almost every line saying things like:

> String cannot be resolved to a type

and

> java.lang.Object cannot be resolved

How to go back to fix it?

Comment: Well, what JRE do you have installed? If it's 8, Java will use 8. If not, it'll use 7. If it's using the wrong one, you'll need to go to your Build Path and fiddle with that.

Comment: I think I have 7, but the build path says 1.8

Comment: Then that's your problem. Eclipse is trying to access a jdk that doesn't exist. You can add 1.7 to the build path and remove 1.8 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a confusion in your eclipse between the Installed JRE in your system and the used JRE in your project, so to resolve point to the installed JRE in your system, like this:

1. **Open your project build path configuration:**

Right click in your project, then choose `properties`-->`Java Build Path`.

[image]

**2. Add a new JRE System Library:**

Click the button <kbd>add Library</kbd> then choose `JRE System Library`:

[image]

**3. Choose the installed JRE Library:**

Click the <kbd>Installed JREs...</kbd> button and choose the installed JRE in your system.

[image]

Hope it helps.